# Удалить данные о регистрации в pypi

Tags: python

У меня есть проект на `PYPI`. Когда я вводил `python setup.py register`, то автоматически был сохранен мой логин и пароль от `pypi`. Как мне их сбросить и пройти регистрацию заного ?

Если ввести `python setup.py register`, то программа просто авторизируется и все.

Comment: попробуйте `~/.pypyirc` переименовать. Чтобы зарегистрирвать проект, загрузить его на PyPI, [удобно `twine` использовать](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine).